# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal' in Anaconda. When I import on terminal I don't get errors.

Tags: python

I've tried running it on Python 3.6.3 and Python 3.5.4  Neither runs when I use text editors.  I've tried Spyder, Idle and Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Your text editors are running different Python version. Figure out where that other version lives, and then run

```
/path/to/other/python -m pip install pygal
```